# Creating a Autosupression List

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Has anyone created an auto suppression list using ssjs?

I am aware that an auto suppression list is nothing but a data extension at the backend of Salesforce Marketing cloud. However, what property can be used to make a data extension an auto suppression list? When I retrieve an already existing auto suppression list using ssjs data extension functions, I do not see any particular property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Auto-Suppression Lists using the SOAP [SuppressionListDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/suppressionlistdefinition.htm) object and either [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm) or old-school [Platform SSJS API functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAPIFunctions.htm).

Here's an example of creating an Auto-Suppression List for a specific CAN-SPAM Send Classification using WSProxy. For other configurations, like suppressing against particular Sender Profiles, please refer to [Interact with Auto-Suppression Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_auto_suppression_lists_via_the_soap_api.htm):

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var listDef = {
    "Name": "My AutoSuppression List",
    "Description": "SSJS generated suppression list",
    "Contexts": [{
      "Client": {
        "ID": "123456789"
      },
      "Context": "BusinessUnit",
      "SendClassificationType": "Marketing",
      "AppliesToAllSends": false
    }]
  };

  var res = prox.createItem("SuppressionListDefinition",listDef);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this ampscript will create a suppression list. List classification denotes what kind of suppression list is needed. More parameters are available in - [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/list.htm)

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

try {
</script>
%%[

var @df, @parentFolder, @createStatusCode, @createStatusMessage, @createErrorCode
set @df = CreateObject("List")
SetObjectProperty(@df, "ListName", "Test List")
SetObjectProperty(@df, "Description", "Test List Description")
SetObjectProperty(@df, "ListClassification", "SuppressionList")

set @createStatusCode = InvokeCreate(@df, @createStatusMessage, @createErrorCode)

]%%
createStatusCode: %%=v(@createStatusCode)=%%
<br>createStatusMessage: %%=v(@createStatusMessage)=%%
<br>createErrorCode: %%=v(@createErrorCode)=%%
<script runat="server">
} catch (e) {
  Write("<br>" + Stringify(e))
}

</script>
```